# Can somebody tell me how to include external javadocs to Oracle JDeveloper (11g)

Tags: javadoc, jdeveloper

I am using some external libraries, and i also want to include their javadocs.
I've searched on the internet, but few documentation exists for JDeveloper. The overall IDE is actually a little noon-intuitive, even though very powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Tools/Manage Libraries to add a library to JDeveloper, or when you add a library to Project Properties, you can include the Class Path, the Doc Path, and the Source Path.  Only the Class Path is required, but if you want to include the javadocs, put their location in the Doc Path.